# Agregar otra opción de patrón a una expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/[IOBETGSAZÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜŸ:|\\/"<>?*']/gi
```

Esta como pueden ver se encarga de encontrar cada uno de estos caracteres en una cadena de texto de Javascript, para intercambiarlos por otros equivalentes al valor de un objeto. Para este caso va a ser:

```
"Zion Y Lennox - La Player"
```

Me gustaría conseguir que no solo seleccione caracteres en especifico de los que se compone la gran mayoría el objeto, sino también la subcadena `" Y "`; que se estructura así: Un solo espacio " " + la letra "Y" + otro espacio " ". Cuando logre encontrarla, la reemplace por la cadena `" & "`. Cabe mencionar si no está de esa forma en especifico no se tenga en cuenta.

Este es el código que tengo funcionando hasta la fecha:

```js
let obj = {
          'I': '1',
          'O': '0',
          'B': '8',
          'E': '3',
          'T': '7',
          'G': '6',
          'S': '5',
          'A': '4',
          'Z': '2',
          'Á': '4',
          'É': '3',
          'Í': '1',
          'Ó': '0',
          'Ú': 'U',
          'Ä': '4',
          'Ë': '3',
          'Ï': '1',
          'Ö': '0',
          'Ü': 'U',
          'Ÿ': 'Y',
          ' Y ': ' & ',
          ':': '-',
          '|': '-',
          '\\': '_',
          '/': '_',
          '"': '_',
          '<': '_',
          '>': '_',
          '?': '_',
          '*': '_',
          "'": '_'
        }



let Title = 'Zion Y Lennox - La Player';


        let var1 = Title.toUpperCase();
        let var2 = var1.replace(/[IOBETGSAZÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜŸ:|\\/"<>?*']| Y /gi, (char) => obj[char]);
        console.log(var2);
```

Comment: ¿espacio en blanco (incluye `\r\n\t\f`) o sólo espacio?

Comment: solo un espacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando un or (o [alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Grupos_y_rangos)): `|`

```
/[IOBETGSAZÁÉÍÓÚÄËÏÖÜŸ:|\\/"<>?*']| Y /gi
```

Y luego agregando esta clave en `obj` para que se reemplace por lo que quieras.

Comment: Funciona, gracias.